# 3d rendering in c : display trouble

Tags: matrix, graphics, 3d

I am trying to implement a simple 3d rendering program without the use of openGL. I have created matrix structures that I use to make a transformation matrix, a view matrix and a projection matrix. The product of this matrices is then divided by the fourth component (w = 1) of the mesh vertices to clip space before applying a viewProjectionMatrix to obtain the screen coordinates of the mesh.

It looks fine if the camera is far away from the mesh, but when I move it closer I obtain something like this :

[image: Picture of the problem]

It looks like every vertice that is not in the view space is displayed at the top of the screen. Do you have any idea of what causes that ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have forgotten to implement **near plane clipping**, which omits any geometry crossing a plane at a small predetermined distance in front of the camera. This is to stop them from crossing the perspective singularity, which is the position of the camera. Any geometry crossing this singularity will be inverted by the perspective projection.

(p.s. a commonly used clipping algorithm is [Sutherland-Hodgman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland%E2%80%93Hodgman_algorithm))